# In which method, should call state management methods of the class in Flutter bloc with rxdart?

Tags: flutter, stream, bloc, rxdart

Firstly, I want to ask is from which method of Stateful widget should I call state management methods. I need to choice two place `init()` method or `build()`. I don't exactly know which method is the appropriate method to call state management methods. Let me try to explain with examples to understand of my question.

I use `rxdart` for dependency injection, used `Stream` and build with `bloc` pattern. Then used `global scope` instead of `single scope`. So I build another class that extend `InheritedWidget` and predefine each of the `of(context)` from the ancestor widget. Then called bloc methods (state management) from each `build()` method of their needed UI class (Stateful or stateless).

In here, my problem is when every time I called from `build` method, some of the function build again and again, unless I need to do. So I fix with another way, that is declare, initialized the `bloc` class and call respective `bloc` class function with `object` from `init` method of stateful class. That is work really. But some of the article said, don't should call from `init` method and only should call from `build` method. I am anxiety with that principles and calling from `init` method not work as `global scope` (Ex: that init stream not work for another widgets). How should I do with that? please tell or guide me with something.

Here is my code flow to better understanding. I show with count down example bloc that work like When count down become 0, the button will appear and press again that button count down again and work same process again.

That is state management bloc

```
class OtpLoginModuleBloc {

  bool isHideResendButton = true;

  final _buttonTimerController = PublishSubject<bool>();
  final _textTimerController = PublishSubject<int>();

  Stream<bool> get buttonTimerStream => _buttonTimerController.stream;
  Stream<int> get textTimerStream => _textTimerController.stream;


  void toAppearResendButtonCountown({required int second}) {
    var duration = const Duration(seconds: 1);
    Timer.periodic(
      duration,
      (Timer timer) {
        if (second == 0) {
          isHideResendButton = !isHideResendButton;
          _buttonTimerController.sink.add(isHideResendButton);
          timer.cancel();
        } else {
          second--;
        }
        _textTimerController.sink.add(second);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Here is ancestor class

```
class _PreModuleState extends State<PreModule> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LoginModuleProvider(
      child: OtpLoginModuleProivder(
        child: MaterialApp(
          theme: themeData(),
          home: const Scaffold(
            body: SplashScreen(),
          ),
          onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.route,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is provider class for global scope

```
class OtpLoginModuleProivder extends InheritedWidget {
  final OtpLoginModuleBloc loginOtpModuleBloc;

  OtpLoginModuleProivder({Key? key, required Widget child})
      : loginOtpModuleBloc = OtpLoginModuleBloc(),
        super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(OtpLoginModuleProivder oldWidget) => true;

  static OtpLoginModuleBloc of(context) {
    return (context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<OtpLoginModuleProivder>()
            as OtpLoginModuleProivder)
        .loginOtpModuleBloc;
  }
}
```

And my problem is here ...

Should I call like that

```
final OtpLoginModuleBloc otpLoginModuleBloc = OtpLoginModuleBloc();

 @override
  void initState() {
    otpLoginModuleBloc.toAppearResendButtonCountown(second: otpCountingTime);
    super.initState();
  }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            const OtpLoginHeader(),
            const SizedBox(
              height: margin50,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: margin100),
              child: buildPinCodeTextField(context, otpLoginModuleBloc),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: margin30,
            ),
            StreamBuilder(
              initialData: otpCountingTime,
              stream: otpLoginModuleBloc.textTimerStream,
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: margin80),
                  child: snapshot.data == 0
                      ? sendOtpButton(otpLoginModuleBloc, otpCountingTime)
                      : Text('Request new OTP in ${snapshot.data}'),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

**OR**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final otpLoginModuleBloc = OtpLoginModuleProivder.of(context);
    otpLoginModuleBloc.toAppearResendButtonCountown(second: otpCountingTime);
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            const OtpLoginHeader(),
            const SizedBox(
              height: margin50,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: margin100),
              child: buildPinCodeTextField(context, otpLoginModuleBloc),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: margin30,
            ),
            StreamBuilder(
              initialData: otpCountingTime,
              stream: otpLoginModuleBloc.textTimerStream,
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: margin80),
                  child: snapshot.data == 0
                      ? sendOtpButton(otpLoginModuleBloc, otpCountingTime)
                      : Text('Request new OTP in ${snapshot.data}'),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

That is my all of my question...
Please help me and guide me ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofc you should go for the latter.
use like this. This way, you can use `_otpLoginModuleBloc` within the class.

```
class _ExampleWidgetState extends State<ExampleWidget> {
  late OtpLoginModuleBloc _otpLoginModuleBloc

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _otpLoginModuleBloc = OtpLoginModuleProivder.of(context);
    return Container();
  }
}
```

In addition, if you need to run the `otpLoginModuleBloc.toAppearResendButtonCountown(second: otpCountingTime);` only ONCE, then use below.

```
class ExampleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExampleWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<ExampleWidget> createState() => _ExampleWidgetState();
}

class _ExampleWidgetState extends State<ExampleWidget> {
  late OtpLoginModuleBloc _otpLoginModuleBloc

  final _otpCountingTime = 1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _otpLoginModuleBloc.toAppearResendButtonCountown(second: _otpCountingTime);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _otpLoginModuleBloc = OtpLoginModuleProivder.of(context);
    return Container();
  }
}
```

This should answer your questions. Thank you.

Oh and don't forget to add `dispose` method inside the `OtpLoginModuleBloc` that cancels `Timer` and closes both `_buttonTimerController` and `_textTimerController` in case you don't need the bloc anymore.

Comment: I understand that call from ```init``` method run only once at starting screen. I also do like that in my project. But the really I want to know is will it work well 
calling from ```init``` method and will it act like as ```global scope``` without calling bloc provider class which extend ```InheritedWidget``` ?

Comment: without `provider` class you will have to pass the `bloc` to each widget manually.
That's why you use the `InheritedWidget` to let flutter to automatically pass `bloc` to the child widgets.

Comment: Oh.. I see. Did you mean calling from ```build```  or ```init``` method not associated with automatically or manually and automatically or manually only associated with  ```InheritedWidget```?

Comment: no no only in init method, because `flutter` manages `child widget tree` with `context`. and in your `provider` it has `context` in it, take a look. so you will have to call the `bloc` from `Widget build` method cuz it provides the `context` while `initState` is not.